# How to draw more attention to this question?

Tags: discussion

How would I possibly get more attention to this question? [Are hiding and obfuscating the URL parameter keys a protection against tampering?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/130055/is-php-array-injection-web-parameter-key-tampering-impossible-without-knowing)

I've asked several questions here and some were luckily quite upvoted. But I really don't see to get the mystery of this question. I asked the question on July 14th already and it just has been viewed 182 times.

This meta-question isn't meant to draw more attention to this specific question but I'm seriously wondering how that is possible. One of my latest questions was asked July 26th and is [already viewed 9624 times](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/131056/what-is-worse-for-password-strength-a-poor-password-policy-or-no-password-polic).

I send a tweet about this question already and also I add a bounty. Nothing seems to increase the amount of views. I clarified the question several times and I think it's not written badly or something.

Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't view it initially because I am not a PHP developer, and did not know the meaning of `mod_rewrite`.

Your title and the initial parts of the question seems you are asking for a workaround or easy way out.

"Does using this obfuscation make X attack impossible?"

The answer is probably no, but to post an answer requires some detailed thought. Especially for someone like me who is not familiar with the techniques you are using.

> How to draw more attention

I know you are asking for more views/attention (and in turn more answers than what you have gotten so far), but what problem are you actually trying to solve? Why is the existing answer not sufficient for you?

**Suggestions**

- Your overall question should be made shorter. I think it could be represented in half the length.
- Ask positively "Does attacker need to know X to perform Z attack?"
  instead of what you are doing now: "Is attack Z impossible without knowing X?"
- Your question will be re-posted to the home page each time you edit, so the title is important. I think your current title is too long, and should be re-worded similarly.
- Avoid editing on unrelated questions. I see you have an "Additionally", and you also added a question in the comments. Handling a complex array of questions in a single Answer is more difficult. Sometimes you just need to let the first question get answered, and then post a new question influenced by the information you've learned so far.

> One of my latest questions was asked July 26th and is [already viewed 9624 times](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/131056/what-is-worse-for-password-strength-a-poor-password-policy-or-no-password-polic).

The question that got so many more views was language-agnostic, and requires no knowledge of a specific programming language. You can have a anything from Windows OS, to Node.JS background and still have a great array of answers. This knowledge helps others solve real-world knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Your simplest way to do this - post a [bounty](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) on it.

> If you’ve asked a good question, edited it with status and progress updates, and still are not receiving answers, you can draw attention to your question by placing a bounty on it.
>
> A bounty is a special reputation award given to answers. It is funded by the personal reputation of the user who offers it, and is non-refundable. If you see a question that has not gotten a satisfactory answer, a bounty may help attract more attention and more answers. Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned reputation, and attach it to any question as a bounty. You do not need to be the asker of the question to offer a bounty on it.